# ...at the bottom-back of your shirt

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

As we regularly use:

> at the **top-left,** at the **bottom right** etc. for describing a picture.

But how should I express that **my shirt has a cut at the back that is at the bottom.**

Can I say:

> There is a cut at the **bottom-back** of my shirt.

Are **bottom-back, top- front** valid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a *dress shirt*, the bottom of the back is actually called the "tail" or "shirttail":

> There is a cut in my shirttail.

The 'bottom' of most garments is called "*the hem*", or possibly "*the fringe*" (the latter is a little old-fashioned), so you could say:

> There is a cut in the hem of my shirt, at the back.

"Top left", and "bottom right" etc are idiomatic, but the words "back" and "front" aren't usually used that way because they describe the whole surface, not just a part of it. If you must describe the location of the cut I would say the most natural way would be:

> There is a cut *at the bottom of my shirt, on the back*.

Comment: If the cut is deliberate tailoring and not a rip, it is called a **vent**.